# What will I add to my code so that when I click the other buttons, the opened element automatically closes?

Tags: javascript

My code works but I have to double click the button I clicked just to close it. I would like that when I click the other button, the opened element automatically closes.

```
<div class="col- menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('pic1'); return false;">Picture</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('description'); return false;">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('size'); return false;">Size</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <p><span id="pic1"><img src="1.jpg"></span></p>
        <p><span id="description" style="display: none;">Cool!</span></p>
        <p><span id="size" style="display: none;"><img src="2.jpg"></span></p>
      </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleStuff(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this:

```
var stuffArr = ['pic1', 'description', 'size'];
function toggleStuff(id) {
  stuffArr.forEach(function(currentId) {
    if(currentId === id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the id''s

Please note this is just demo code to give you an idea

```js
function toggleStuff (id){
 //get list of ids
 var pic1 = document.getElementById ("pic1");
 var size = document.getElementById ("size");

var idSize = 2;
var idArray = Array ("pic1","size");

for (var i = 0; i  < idSize; i++){
 if (idArray.indexOf (i) == id){
 //display id
}else {
//hide id
}
}
}
```

Comment: This is an example not production ready code do some research on arrays and loops basically you need to disable all other elements when enabling another one you could do this manually but a loop is faster and easier

Answer (score 0):

One out of millions of possible solutions:

```js
function toggleStuff(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id)
  el.classList.toggle('visible');
  document.querySelectorAll('.togglable:not(#'+id+')').forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('visible');
  })
}
```

```css
.togglable {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col- menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('pic1'); return false;">Picture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('description'); return false;">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('size'); return false;">Size</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p><span id="pic1" class="togglable">PIC1</span></p>
  <p><span id="description" class="togglable">DESCRIPTION</span></p>
  <p><span id="size" class="togglable">SIZE</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why here it's working but when I put it in my code, It just show everything.

Comment: See I added a css class `togglable` on the span elements, and a little snippet of css along.

Comment: If you don't know how to add css, let me know. The class `togglable` replaces the `style="display: none;"` from your code.

Comment: So if this is the anwer you were looking for, remember to pick it as your answer.